# Code to find the maximum number of array using recursion always returns the last item in the array

Tags: java, arrays

The following code will always write `0`. Why is that and how do I fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] Array= {5,4,6,3,7,2,8,1,9,0};
    int max=0;
    System.out.println(maximum(Array,Array.length-1,max));
}

public static int maximum(int[] Array,int length,int max)
{
    if (length!=0)
    {
        if(max<Array[length])
        {
            max=Array[length];
        }

        maximum(Array,length-1,max); 
    }

    return max;  
}
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "not working".

Comment: means it always get 0 in return

Comment: @ShahiryarArif I edited to reflect that, hope that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `maximum` recursively, you don't write returned value.

```
    if (length!=0)
    {
        if(max<Array[length])
        {
            max=Array[length];
        }

        max = maximum(Array,length-1,max); //rewrite max variable
    }

    return max;
```

**EDIT**

And need to initialize first `max` value to `Array[0]`

```
int max=Array[0];
System.out.println(maximum(Array,Array.length-1,max));
```

Comment: @ShahiryarArif Also, it should be `length != -1` - right now, if the maximum is the first item in the array, it'll only give the second-highest number.

Comment: @ShahiryarArif - I changed my answer